# filtering escaped angle brackets in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, escaping, security, entities

I have a javascript feature that allows users to place arbitrary text strings on a page. I don't want them to be able to insert html or other code, just plain text.

So I figure that stripping out all angle brackets(`<` `>`) would do the trick. (I don't care if they have 'broken' html on the page, or that they're not able to put angle brackets in their text) Then I realized I had to filter escaped angle brackets (`&lt;` `&gt;`) and probably others.

What all do I need to filter out, for security? Will removing all angle brackets do the trick?

Comment: I don't see why you need to filter out escaped angle-brackets. They'll simply appear as angle brackets when presented on a web page, without actually behaving like HTML.

Comment: Marcelo will you put that as an answer? Then I can accept it :)

Comment: It depends on how he does it. He should test to be sure whether your statement applies to his situation or not.

Comment: George - are there any browsers that will parse escaped angle brackets as actual html?

Comment: No, not when escaped. I might have misunderstood Marcelo's comment. It just doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the first thing you do is replace `&` with `&amp;`

a) For HTML content, just `<` should be enough.

b) For attribute values, for example if it is going in `<input name="sendtoserver" value="custom text"/>` you need to take care of double-quotes, but that is all that is necessary. Still it is good to also do `<` and `>`.

It depends on the context. If you want to play it safe, tell your JavaScript to use `innerText` which does not need encoding, but you may want to set the css to `white-space:pre-wrap`. This is less error prone, but also less browser-compatible.

c) On a loosely related note, when escaping JavaScript strings terminators using backslashes, The item that might sneak up on you is if you place content in a script, you need to take care of `</script>` (not case sensitive) You can just escape `</` or `/` should be enough

Comment: If all angel brackets are removed, wouldn't that make all the other things moot?

Comment: Item `a` is not enough to take care of `b`. For example inserting JavaScript in an `onmouseover="..bad code here.."` could happen if you don't encode `"`. Item `c` really only applies to escaping JavaScript. Edited

Comment: If item a applies, then b would never happen, right? `<input ...` would just become `input...` and thus wouldn't be parsed, right?

Comment: Glad you brought that up. If user only has control over `custom text`, but it is placed inside an `input`. then you need to escape `"`. That is what I mean by it depends on the context / whether you use `a` or `b` or `c` depends on where the custom text is used. You need to encode differently depending. If you want to be safe, you can always do **both** `a` and `b`.

Comment: Ah! I see what you're saying now. But if it's not a property of a tag, but rather text within tags, removing angle brackets should be okay, right?

Comment: Yes, the only thing necessary in that case is to replace `&` with `&amp;` and `<` with `&lt;`.

Comment: Not for security, but just to be nice. If somebody types `please install multiply&divide handlers`. It will show to the screen as `install multiply÷ handlers`. But if you do the ampersand as I am suggesting, the code will be `please install multiply&amp;divide handlers` which results in correct behavior. **Furthermore**, if you replace `<` before `&` and someone types `If it is <5`, the result will be `If it is &amp;lt;5` which on the screen looks like `If it is &lt;5`. **instead you should** replace `&` before `<` which results in correct behavior.

Answer (score 3):

> Will removing all angle brackets do the trick?

Just replace all angle brackets with their escaped form. That way, people can write as much "code" as they like, and it just shows up as plain-text instead.